# Referencing a NuGet MSBuild Task within After.Solution.sln.targets

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

What is the proper way to use a NuGet MSBuild Task within the `After.Solution.sln.targets` file?

### The Problem

In `Directory.Build.props`, a package is referenced:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include ="MSBuildTasks" Version="1.5.0.235"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

In `After.Solution.sln.targets`, I try to use the package:

```xml
  <Target Name="Zip" AfterTargets="Build">
    ...
    <Zip
      ... />
  </Target>
```

*The contents of this task itself are not important - I have verified that it works in `Directory.Build.targets`.*

When MSBuild is executed, it is unable to find the `Zip` task.

### The Ugly Solution

The only functional solution I have been able to find is adding a `UsingTask` in `After.Solution.sln.targets` that points directly to the package's .dll on the disk:

```xml
<UsingTask TaskName="Zip"
  AssemblyFile = "C:\Users\...\.nuget\packages\msbuildtasks\1.5.0.235\tools\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll"/>
```

This obviously has a number of downsides:

1. It's a hard coded path instead of relative.
2. It would not handle any package version changes.

Is there a solution that fixes these issues?

Comment: A solution doesn't import the Directory.Build.props or Directory.Build.targets files. Can you use the built-in `ZipDirectory` task?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Yes, I understand the root issue.  I'm just hoping there's an alternate approach that would work here that I'm not aware of.

I don't believe I can use ZipDirectory - it doesn't support include/exclude of specific file types.

Comment: I assumed from your problem description that you expected the `Directory.Build.props` to be used by the solution. It seems that you also expected a solution to have `PackageReference`s. I trust that you are aware that builds performed in Visual Studio ignore the `After.Solution.sln.targets` file. Instead of after the solution build, can the Zip step be performed within a project? e.g. if the solution is an .exe project and a set of .dll projects referenced by the .exe project, then the zip step could be at the end of the .exe project.

Comment: For scenarios where there isn't a single natural 'endpoint' project that depends on all the required projects and files, you can create a project that just performs the Zip step. In the solution file, set this project to depend on all the relevant projects. To create this project see the [`Microsoft.Build.NoTargets`](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/tree/main/src/NoTargets) SDK type.

Comment: Yeah, I included that context to illustrate that I am hoping for a solution that looks like that / has those upsides.  And yes, I'm aware I'd have to use the terminal to call MSBuild (or install an extension).
The Zip step can't belong to each individual project.  It refers to "shared" data that 1. Is conceptually shared between all projects and 2. causes build issues when every project tries to zip from and to the same path simultaneously.
NoTargets looks like a potentially viable workaround.  I'd prefer not to have an extra project, but it seems like it might be the best option.